# Why am I still lagging in Star Craft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

- 17.3" FULL HD (1920X1080) LED LCD
- nVIDIA GeForce® GT 425M w/1GB GDDR3
- Intel GMA HD4500
- 640m core i7 processor
- 8 GB RAM
- 64 bit OS

For some reason, when there is a batle in progress it appears as if my graphics card or something is not powerful enough.  Shouldn't these specs be more than enough to handle Starcraft II?

What could I do to improve my laptop?

Comment: Is it the Sager NP7130?

Comment: @matthew read yes it is

Comment: Good place to look at your graphics card is notebookcheck.net http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Geforce-GT-425M.34152.0.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to improve a specific laptop to run a specific game better.

Comment: @Frank I think like you, but just to know, where can we post this type of questions? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the latest drivers from NVidia for your primary card.
2. Make sure the primary card is enabled and is being used, since the onboard Intel card is garbage.

Comment: how would i go about enabling it / checking if its on?

Comment: You'd probably enable it in the BIOS.  I would assume the drivers come with a control panel app where you could check things out.

Answer (score 1):

Now, frame rates (FPS) around ~30 is still considered playable. If you are experiencing worse frame rates, that means you are running your quality settings too high. Try running the game on Low or Medium to get better performance. If you are running the Full native resolution of your screen, you will definitely stress your graphics chip in a higher setting.

If you installed the Nvidia drivers properly, I believe Optimus would switch to your Nvidia graphics chip to play games like Starcraft 2. Everything is worse on the Intel chip.

Answer (score -2):

wbat's the clock frequency on your processor? starcraft 2 only supports 2 cores, so if you have a 2.0 ghz quad core, you're effectively playing starcraft 2 on 2 cores at that frequency, which is slightly below recommended settings.

Comment: Clock speed isn't the best metric in the days of multicore CPUs. Any i7 processor is going to be well over the minimum processor specs for SCII.