# Why is Star Craft II lagging with these specs?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I still lagging in Star Craft II?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14832/why-am-i-still-lagging-in-star-craft-ii)

- 17.3" FULL HD (1920X1080) LED LCD w/nVIDIA GeForce® GT 425M w/1GB GDDR3 + Intel GMA HD4500
- 640m core i7 processor
- 8 GB RAM
- 64 bit OS

For some reason, when there is a batle in progress it appears as if my graphics card or something is not powerful enough.  Shouldn't these specs be more than enough to handle Starcraft II?

What could I do to improve my laptop?

Comment: how much free ram do you have prior to running the game and what % utilization is the CPU at when the computer is idle?

Comment: Is this a dedicated video card or integrated into the motherboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I still lagging in Star Craft II?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14832/why-am-i-still-lagging-in-star-craft-ii)

Comment: Definitely an exact dupe.  The migration process sucks.  @Anna: Read the specs in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the dupe: there should be a remote duplicate detector, and/or people should stop cross-posting questions. All we see on Programmers.SE is that this is clearly completely out of our scope.

Comment: @Matthew: I can't tell from the specs without looking up the card and I figured I'd ask here in case someone else was in the same boat.